# MS VC++ inline asm syntax error

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

```
long long k;
_asm
{
rdtsc:=A(k);
};
```

This code gives this error:

> error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand'; found ':'
>
> error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found ':'

P.S. MS Visual C++ 2008

Comment: why do you put something in an `_asm` block that is obviously not assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rdtsc:=A(k);` is not a valid instruction. Only labels can appear before `:`, and after that there must be a valid instruction, which of course `=A(k)` can't be. If you're doing an assignment, that's not an assembly instruction either

Answer (score -1):

Without being given the full source, I would say immediately that you are using a Pascal-like assignment syntax instead of C++.

Try:

```
rdtsc=A(k); // Without the colon
```

Rather than:

```
rdtsc:=A(k);
```

Comment: an assignment is not an assembly instruction